# Vue.js change {{ }} tags

Tags: vue.js

I want to change the `{{ something }}` by `<% something %>` in Vue.js, how could I achieve that, is it even possible?

An equivalent for what I look for in AngularJS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should modify the [`delimiters`](http://vuejs.org/api/#delimiters) property of configuration object.

```
Vue.config.delimiters = ['<%', '%>']
```

**Edit: This solution works for Vue 1.x and lower. See @Skip and @jaynabonne responses for Vue 2.x solution**

Comment: Ah, see the other answer.

Answer (score 102):

With the latest version (2.0.5), the above doesn't work. Rather than assigning to the global config, you pass the delimiters as an option to the Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    delimiters: ["<%","%>"]
});
```

At least, that's what I had to do to make it work.

Comment: You saved my day. I am sticking to compose a standalone vuejs html and serve it as a template in flask. This is the easiest and best solution I can find.

Answer (score 29):

I am running Vue 2.1.0 standalone and this is what I had to use

```
Vue.options.delimiters = ['{[{', '}]}'];
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are working with Vue 3.x, the [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#delimiters) tells you to do this:

```
Vue.createApp({
  // Delimiters changed to ES6 template string style
  delimiters: ['${', '}']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to change template engine in vue js

```
 new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'hello world'
        } ,
        delimiters: ['<%' , '%>']
    });
```