# vue js with flask jinja2 conflict data rendering

Tags: python, flask, vue.js, jinja2

I have code and followed up below reference but doesn't affect when working with repeat -

```
<p v-for="item in questionDataSet.options">
  <label>
  <input name="question-data-row" type="radio" 
    v-model="requestData.surveyDetails.answerSelection" value="{{item.key}}">
  <span>{{item.value}}</span>
```

here {{item.key}} is not working in radio value while have updated the jinja2 template binding but {{item.value}} still displaying well.

My JSON data set for reference -

```
{"options": [{"key": "A", "value": "Lucknow"}, {"key": "B", "value": "New Delhi"}, {"key": "C", "value": "Ahmedabad"}, {"key": "D", "value": "Patna"}], "question": "India’s first ever ‘Khadi Haat’ has launched in which city?"}
```

I have followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46214132/how-can-i-combine-vue-js-with-flask/49880098#49880098) for solution but not work fully.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In attributes, use `v-bind` (or its shorthand `:`), not interpolations. So, instead of:

```
value="{{item.key}}"
```

Do:

```
:value="item.key"
```

Example:

```
<input name="question-data-row" type="radio" 
                    v-model="requestData.surveyDetails.answerSelection" :value="item.key">
```

Comment: Tried your solution before but not worked template rendering gets no display to show,only white screen...

Comment: Ah, I see, perhaps you have a different issue. Can you try: `:value="'{{item.key}}'"` ?

Comment: it doesn't work @acdcjunior. It's taking the {{item.key}} in my v-model as string not it's actual value.Even on inspecting on chrome it's showing {{item.key}} in value attribute not it's actual value. Btw thanks for the suggestion.