# Serve simple vuejs page with flask (1 server)

Tags: vue.js, flask

Internet is full of examples of applications served with Flask (api) and Vue.js (client), but since Vue is a SPA it make sense to serve it with flask as well.
I didn't find any help, especially where the App is stored in an external js.

With Firefox I get error for a disallowed type:

> Loading module from “http://localhost:5000/static/App” was blocked
> because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).

On Chrome I just get file not found since it tries to get the App file instead of App.vue.

Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 {% raw %}
  <div id="app">
   {{ message }}
  </div>
 {% endraw %}

</body>
<script type="module" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='myvue.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

The myvue.js

```
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
});
```

The app.vue (simply got from another example on SO):

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <h1>My Todo App!</h1>
    <!-- <TodoList/> -->
</div>
</template>
```

Note that the {{message}} is useless there and can be removed. I suspect the template is also wrong, but I can't reach that point.
I'd like to be able to work without the CLI or at least being able to do all by myself to avoid another layer of dependencies (npm scares me with the huge list of deprecated stuff)

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? I have a very very similar problem.

Comment: @BaldDude I gave up

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make sense to serve a Vue SPA app from Flask to my mind. What are  you actually trying to achieve?

If you are looking to setup a configuration where a SPA app can access data on a Flask server, then the typical configuration is to build a VueJS SPA app using the CLI and Node, then deliver the compiled build directly from your web server (e.g. Apache, IIS). There's no reason to pipe the delivery of the SPA app via Flask, all that does is add a bunch of overhead.

Use Flask to expose a REST API that your SPA app can call (e.g. using AXIOS) to retrieve/write data, etc.

Comment: The reason is simple: I want people to be able to get my app and use it locally without needing to install 2 server. I wanted to be able to develope that way as well if it's possible.

Comment: Each to his own, but it'll be way faster just to install a web server on the box instead of trying to force Flask into a configuration you wouldn't want for production anyway.