# Twig string variables contain Javascript code that is compiled by VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, twig

I have a problem with pass a string that contains Javascript code (ex. `{{console.log('Somethings')}}`) as Twig string variable.
Twig template:

```
<div id="app">
<h1 class="main-heading heading--larger heading--left">{{ page_title }}</h1>
</div
```

Javascript with VueJS v2:

```
new Vue({
            el: '#app',
        })
```

If I pass a string that contains Javascript code (ex. `{% set page_title = '{{console.log('Somethings')}}' %}`), I will see browser prints

> Somethings!

in console tab.

I want the browser do not run this JS code ('**console.log('Somethings')**'). How I can do?

Comment: Not sure how that would result in the console printing `something`, u did not add any `<script>`-tags around it?

Comment: I am sure that the console printed Somethings!. I added script. I need VueJS avoid compile `<h1 class="main-heading heading--larger heading--left">{{console.log('Somethings')}}</h1>` with page_title = '{{console.log('Somethings')}}'

Comment: I see what you mean now, either change [twig's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21794497/use-custom-delimiters-in-the-current-twig-template) delimeters or [vue's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628558/vue-js-change-tags) as they are using the same one's

Comment: changing the delimeters doesn't solve the issue because user can input the same delimeter of VueJS.
Let say we change delimeter of VueJS to "${" and "}".
Then user inputs "${ console.log('something') }"

Comment: It is not possible to run statements inside interpolations (`{{}}`). Vue uses the template is used to create a virtual dom representation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following link may fix your issue https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/4223

Comment: The link may or may not answer the question, but link-only answer are discouraged on stackoverflow