# Vue.js change single bracket delimiter {} tags

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way to change single bracket delimiters in vue.js to something custom??
for example:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ background: theme_color }"></div>
```

change "{  }" to "&[  ]" :

```
<div v-bind:style="&[ background: theme_color ]"></div>
```

I know how to change double bracket delimiters from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33628558/vue-js-change-tags) but no guide to single bracket delimiters.

Comment: I don't think you can change that because they're not really delimiters, it's a javascript object.

Comment: @StevenB. oh my god, I was blind thank you much. now I think the main problem I was trying to solve does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.config.delimiters = ['&[', ']']

use this in configuration

Comment: I know how to change {{ }} tag I want to change { } tag too.